# Using netsh in powershell: save store location for multiple commands

Tags: powershell, dns, location, store, netsh

I have a powershell script which is designed to modify the domain's ipsec policy by adding an ip address to a specified filterlist. The problem is that when running `netsh store location=domain domain=our.domain.com` in my powershell script, it doesn't remember the store location for following commands. I have tried a workaround by creating a text file which is then run from powershell as `netsh -f "path\to\textfile.txt"` but it doesn't seem to work. You will find the relevant script block below. Domain is set correctly, as it works when run directly in netsh.

```
$command = "ipsec static
    set store location=domain domain=our.domain.com
    add filter filterlist=$FILTERLIST
        protocol=ANY srcaddr=$ip
        srcmask=255.255.255.255
        dstaddr=ME 
        description='IP address blocked' 
        mirrored=YES"
    $($command.Trim()) | out-file $($DIR+"\netsh\temp.txt")
    netsh -f $($DIR+"\netsh\temp.txt")
    remove-item $($DIR+"\netsh\temp.txt")
```

I didn't get it to work yet, but as I'm about to do that, it would be nice to know if there are other better-engineered solutions for that. Im running PowerShell v.1.0

Comment: Okay, I figured out a good way to perform the task. Thanks to powerful PowerShell pipelining, what you got to do is `$command | netsh` where `$command`is a valid netsh command (script above contains mistakes) - and thats it :)

Comment: btw, you're probably not running powershell v1 - the install directory is always v1.0 (long story). The date on the startup banner should tell you: 2006 = v1, 2009 = v2, 2012 = v3

Answer (score 0):

Use a here string `@"` ... `"@`  with each line of your script being on separate lines in between. and pipe the command to `netsh`

```
@"
winhttp show proxy
winhttp show proxy
"@ | netsh
```